# Why ntpq shows auth bad?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have two ubuntu 18.04 machines with ntpd ntpsec-1.1.0+419 installed. The ubuntu-1 has access to public internet and it synchronizes time with ntp pools provided by ubuntu like 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org. The ubuntu-2 does not have access to the public internet and it synchronizes time with ubuntu-1. There is a symmetric key created that is used for NTP authentication between ubuntu-1 and ubuntu-2.

Everything is working fine, time is synchronizing and NTP messages are authenticated.

But when I check associations on ubuntu-2 I see auth: bad:

```
# ntpq -c as

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 19530  d61a   yes   yes   bad  sys.peer    sys_peer  1
```

What does the 'bad' exactly mean in this printout? And what I can do to see 'ok' instead of 'bad'?

ntp.conf on ubuntu-1 (shortened with auth related conf only):

```
keys /etc/ntp.keys
trustedkey 1
```

ntp.conf on ubuntu-2 (shortened with auth related conf only):

```
keys /etc/ntp.keys
trustedkey 1
server ubuntu-1 key 1
```

ntp.keyes are same on both nodes:

```
1 MD5 V?^F@BCwwt)6yqgg7E|,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug in the ntpsec. Ntpq says "bad" in auth column for working servers because ntpd says the server is bad. The bug was reported to ntpsec development in https://gitlab.com/NTPsec/ntpsec/issues/513 and a correction was done in the ntpsec 1.1.3.

The bad actually means that the authentication failed but the information is wrong in ntpsec older than 1.1.3.